# SKSpriteNode partial touch detection

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a weird issue related to SkSpriteNode touch detection.
I'm using a SkScene with some SkSpriteNode subclassed sprites which implement the touchesBegan method, following some of the examples found here.

If I tap on a given sprite, it detects the touch, but only partially. There are some areas on it that do not respond to the tap. The sprite is not transparent, it's fully opaque.

I'm building an Universal iOS App, using xcode 5.02 and targeting iOS 7. The issue happens using the simulator or real devices.

Has somebody experienced a similar issue? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Do these subclassed SKSpriteNodes have children?